# Initializers are not allowed in ambient context

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

TypeScript version of both windows/system32 and VS is same i.e. 3.0.3 but I'm still receiving an error.

[image]

```
export declare class ApplicationInitStatus {
  private appInits;
  private resolve;
  private reject;
  private initialized;
  readonly donePromise: Promise<any>;
  readonly done = false;
  constructor(appInits: (() => any)[]);
}
```

Error at `readonly done = false;` in this statement.

Comment: You need to post some code and, if relevant, insert the picture. Just a link is not a good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you use `declare`in a `d.ts` file the class must not contain any code (including initialization of fields). `declare` is used to tell the typescript compiler about classes that already are defined in Javscript (for interoperability).

If you want to create a new class in Typescript remove the `declare` and move the code to a `ts` file.

If you want to declare a class that exists in Javacript remove the `readonly done = false` replace it with `readonly done: boolean`  or `readonly done: false`  (the `false` literal type not the value `false`)